# php script on iis to copy a folder over a windows network

Tags: php, iis

Im trying to use php to copy a folder and contents including subfolders over a windows network using windows scheduler running a php script.

I want to setup a control panel so a user can access a web page that can edit the scheduler time. Is it possible to edit the windows scheduler using php. Also, how can I give php access to the shared folder over the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a poor tool for such a job. Why not use something like [xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)? It'd be far more efficient in a single command, than using what would have to be a many-many line PHP script.

You can have PHP call Windows internally directly via [COM](http://php.net/com) which would presumably give you access to the scheduler. However, you'd have to play with the permissions carefully. PHP/webserver would have to have access to the scheduler, and the job would have to run with high enough privileges that it could deal with network resources - the default IIS user account does NOT have those privileges.

Comment: yes, you are right. I guess im looking at this from the GUI. I would love to be able to setup a user panel so a user can run this job or schedule it. Its not going to be a lot of users, and I see it just reading all the files and only copying the files that have been modified since last run.

Comment: Does php have a exec() equivalent for windows?

Comment: i.e <?php exec("xcopy \\pc1\share \\pc2\share /s /e"); ?> I suppose I could try that out for starters.

Comment: exec and related functions work on windows as on unix, they'll just use cmd.exe instead of whatever unix shell is available (e.g. /bin/sh).